# Can we find a basis such that $[T]_{B^\prime}$ is a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:P_2 \to P_2$ be defined by $T(p(x)) = x\frac{dp}{dx} + \frac{dp}{dx}$ and $B = \{ 1,x,x^2 \}$.

We can find that $[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$.

The eigenvalues of $T$ are thus the solutions of $\lambda$ to the characteristic polynomial $\det(\lambda I - [T]_B)=0$ which are $\lambda_1=0, \lambda_2 = 1, \lambda_3 = 2$.

My question is as follows: Considering the eigenvalues of $T$, is it possible for a basis $B^\prime$ for $P_2$ with respect to which $[T]_{B^\prime}$ is a diagonal matrix, to exist?

My instinct tells me that the answer is no, and that $\lambda_1 = 0$ plays a role in that. But to be honest, I am simply grasping this out of the air. Can someone please give me some clarity and reasoning to answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $0,1,2$ are the columns $1,2$ and $3$ respectively of $$V=\pmatrix{1&1&1\\0&1&2\\0&0&1}.$$  this can be written as $$AV = V\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}$$ in other words, with respect to the basis consisting of the columns of $V,$ the matrix representing the linear transformation $T$ is the diagonal matrix $$ \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}.$$

$\bf edit:$  the reason $AV = VD$ is we can write the eigenvector relations as $$Av_1=0v_1\,, Av_2 = 1v_2, Av_3 = 2v_3.$$  these three equations can be combined into $$A\pmatrix{v_1&v_2&v_3} =\pmatrix{Av_1&Av_2&Av_3} =\pmatrix{v_1&v_2&v_3}\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}   $$

Comment: Thank you! :). Is $A$ the matrix $[T]_B$ in this case? :)

Comment: @Dillon, that is right.

Comment: @Dillon, please see my edit. i left out the part on how i found the eigenvectors. if you have trouble finding eigenvectors, let me know.

Comment: Thank you! :). This answer was very clear and explained everything nicely :). Can you please have a look at this question? I do not know how to answer it, because I have no examples of the notation used so I cannot understand the question - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268928/what-does-the-notation-t-b-prime-to-b-mean

Comment: @Dillon, i wrote up an answer for that too. in fact i was writing up an answer once before and question got deleted. i had to do it again!

Comment: Sorry about that. With SE going offline so often earlier, I thought the post might not have posted correctly, so I deleted it and reposted it :)

Answer (score 1):

As eigenspaces of any matrices are linearly independent if all the eigen values are unique then it can be diagonalized in some basis. Let $g(\lambda)$ be the [geometric multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Geometric_multiplicity) corresponding to the eigen value $\lambda$ and let $a(\lambda)$ be the [algebraic multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity) then $1 \le g(\lambda) \le a(\lambda)$. As all eigen values are unique, $g(\lambda)=1$ for all eigen values and thus sum of dimensions of all eigen spaces is equal to the dimension of the space the matrix/linear operator acts on. This is a necessary sufficient condition for being diagonalizable. In such a case you can diagonalize the matrix in the way the example depicts here [diagonalizable matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Examples).